# Is there a way to make a confirmation in Discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, confirmation

I have a Discord bot and I'd like to know how I can create a confirmation for my `purgeroles` command. Here's the command currently:

```py
@client.command(aliases = ['delroles', 'deleteroles', 'cleanseroles'])
async def purgeroles(ctx):
  embed=discord.Embed(title="Purging (deleting) roles...")
  embedcomplete=discord.Embed(title="All possible roles have been purged (deleted)!")
  if (not ctx.author.guild_permissions.manage_roles):
    await ctx.reply("Error: User is missing permission `Manage Roles`")
    return
  await ctx.reply(embed=embed)
  for role in ctx.guild.roles:
    try:
      await role.delete()
    except:
      pass
  await ctx.reply(embed=embedcomplete)
```

I don't want the bot to just delete all of the roles on command, in case someone runs the command by accident. Is there anyway I can make the bot wait until the author says a message to confirm whether or not the bot should continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=client%20wait_for#discord.Client.wait_for) for this type of stuff.

```py
@client.command(aliases = ['delroles', 'deleteroles', 'cleanseroles'])
async def purgeroles(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Are you sure you want to run this command? (yes/no)")

    def check(m): # checking if it's the same user and channel
        return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel

    try: # waiting for message
        response = await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=30.0) # timeout - how long bot waits for message (in seconds)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError: # returning after timeout
        return

    # if response is different than yes / y - return
    if response.content.lower() not in ("yes", "y"): # lower() makes everything lowercase to also catch: YeS, YES etc.
        return

    # rest of your code
```

Comment: It did work as intended, but is there a way to have 2 options with it allowing "yes" and "y"? I tried doing `if response.content.lower() != "yes" or "y":` but if I typed "y" or "yes" in the channel, it wouldn't do anything.

Comment: Yes, you can.  I just edited my answer. You can, either way, write something like `if response.content.lower() != "yes" or response.content.lower() != "y":` or make it clearer - `if response.content.lower() not in ("yes", "y"):`. If you want more options e.g. "ok" - you can simply add them after comma.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `client.wait_for`.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('$greet'):
        channel = message.channel
        await channel.send('Say hello!')

        def check(m):
            return m.content == 'hello' and m.channel == channel

        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
        await channel.send('Hello {.author}!'.format(msg))
```

[More info in the Discord docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=client%20wait_for#discord.Client.wait_for).